# Intern html reporter

Tags: javascript, reporting, intern

I'm writing functional testing using Intern and I would like to get an html report like the one provided by SauceLabs [[img]](http://developers.mobilesystem7.com/static/img/sauceLabs_intern_uiQueue.png).
I'm not interested to get a live reporter and I'm not interested in getting a code coverage report, but an html page stating all failed/passed tests as shown into the above image.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to build a [custom reporter](https://theintern.github.io/intern/#custom-reporters) that generated what you wanted.  The [WebDriver reporter](https://github.com/theintern/intern/blob/master/lib/reporters/WebDriver.js) is similar to what you want, but it designed to generate HTML when running under the [client.html](https://github.com/theintern/intern/blob/master/client.html) runner.  It could be adapted to output an HTML file relatively easily.